# How to place a dynamic image on different drawable

Tags: java, android

I would like to ask if I'm developing a 4 inch based app device and has a 100x100 px image button, what would be my dynamic images to be placed on the drawables? xhdpi, hdpi, mdpi,ldpi and so on to make it responsive every time it is installed on different devices.

Answer (score 0):

Did you checked out the related best practices for [Multiple Screen supports](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) from [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com). It explains nicely how to make layouts fully responsive

Read this article thoroughly and you will get what you want.

Comment: Yes, I did checked it out but that wasn't so clear and understandable for me.